# TwitterKit: Shared twitter instance not retaining authenticated session

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-fabric

I've got an iOS app using twitter kit to post a tweet, and the authentication doesn't seem to stick.

For example, I have this code I'm using to authenticate:

```
    [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession*session, NSError* error){

        TWTRSession* session2 = [[Twitter sharedInstance] session];
        //session2 is nil here but session is not

        if(!error){
            [self postTweet];
        }

    }];
```

And even during the callback for a successful login, the `[Twitter sharedInstance]` object doesn't have a session, which according to the documentation means the authentication has failed.  What could possibly be going wrong?